# Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"

Tags: angular

> Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"

When i use **Http**  Service injection it throwing error

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class ToDoService{
    constructor (http: Http) {}

    getTODOS():any{       
        return "";
        // return this.http
        //    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        //    .map(res => res.json().data);
    }  
}
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/LRc4VLOzhJjql03kguX8?p=options&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 6):

I got the same exception in Firefox.
Please try another browser to do the debug.

In my case, FireBug only shows the  "Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"", and no more information.

But in Chrome, it shows more, like :

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.eval (http://localhost/UI/app/service/order/order.service.js:14:14)
    at eval (http://localhost/UI/app/service/order/order.service.js:57:4)
    at eval (http://localhost/UI/app/service/order/order.service.js:58:3)
Evaluating http://localhost/UI/node_modules/rxjs
Evaluating http://localhost/UI/app/service/order/order.service.js
Evaluating http://localhost/UI/app/component/order/order.module.js
Error loading http://localhost/UI/app/component/order/order.module.js
```

Then base on these exception trace, I catch my bug.
Here attach the root cause of my bug for your reference.

In some example of online offical doc, it import Observable with  " import { Observable } from 'rxjs';"

But it would cause previous exception in my project.
Change it to " import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; ", then it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the `map` operator from rxjs package. It resolved my problem.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

If you use `do` and `catch` methods you should have two more imports:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Here is the code for your ToDo service:

```
import {Injectable}     from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ToDoService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) {
  }

  getToDos(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
}
```

See the edited code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gQeTZ1oUTXk8s600zPpC?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview)

Comment: can you make this a runnable plnker http://plnkr.co/edit/LRc4VLOzhJjql03kguX8?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I edited it. It works on my local environment. For some reason, dependency injection doesn't work on that website online

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `http` variable private or public to have access to it, else it will just be visible in the constructor.

```
constructor (private http: Http) {}
```

Comment: i am still getting this error. Please check plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/LRc4VLOzhJjql03kguX8?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

it may be because of template reference variables which are misspelled.

```
<input id="user_name" #usernameUpdateRef="ngModel" name="user_name" class="form-control" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="testimonial.user_name"
                                    />
   <div *ngIf="usernameUpdateRef.errors && (usernameUpdateRef.dirty || usernameaRef.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div [hidden]="!usernameUpdateRef.errors.required">username is required</div>
    </div>
```

usernameaRef is misspelled so throwing error

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to import `HttpModule`

from app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be handle error like this.

**On Promise**

```
 Promise.resolve("code to resolve Promise")
     .then("code to execute on callBack")
     .catch( reason => { console.log(reason) } )
```

**On Observable (that it's your case)**

```
var subscription = source.subscribe(
  data => console.log(data),
  err => console.log(err)
);
```

TRY THIS

```
getTODOS():any{       
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
       .map(res => res.json().data);
       .catch(this.handleError);
  }  
public handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw it mentioned that adding

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

helped.

Comment: can you make this as working demo? http://plnkr.co/edit/LRc4VLOzhJjql03kguX8?p=options&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Please start the Plunker from a working Angular2 TS template. Just use the `[New | V]` button in the Plunker editor.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue and reached here looking for a solution. In the end it turned out that I had missed 'http://' from the URL.